# how to get a SQL to a Data Transfer Object?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Hello friends i am currently working on migration my project from asp.net to asp.net core and am facing a few issues with the data transfer object, where i cannot use SQL Query any more to fetch the data.
I get the following as my error

the error is as follows. (Database Facade does not contain a definition for 'SQL Query' and no accessible extension method 'SQL Query' accepting a first argument of type 'Database Facade' could be found.("are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"))

result.data which i have commented is the old version.

Following is my code and that i have used and trying to use.

```js
result.data = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<sysmstatusgroup_dto>(sqlFinal).ToList();
```

how do i use the following code to suite asp.net core 3.0 ?

Comment: Your code seems weird, are you trying to run a SQL query against a MongoDB or a MongoDB query against an SQL database?

Comment: how to simply output sql query to a dto? this is what i want to know on how to do. May be if there is a way please do guide me my friend.